# installing custom font using (font face)

Tags: css, fonts, frontend

I use Brackets code editor and it works perfectly in the live preview, but when I upload it to the actual site, it defaults to Arial. I put the font in the CSS folder, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work on the live site.

**Here is my code.**

```
font-face {
    font-family: BMgermar;
    src: url('http://example.com/css/BMgermar.TTF') format('truetype');
}
```

*Your response will greatly appreciated.*

Comment: it should be `@font-face { ... }`